# How to update fragments in viewpager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, android-json

I'm sure this was already answered before, but I need simple expanation of how to achieve this. I've seen so much examples that I'm competely lost and confused at the moment.

My application is built in this way

[image]

Idea is that user logs in through facebook (works) and then in frag #1 is a list with recent friend activities, frag #2 is kind of a user profile and in frag #3 is a friend list.

I'm using facebook login in fragment activity, there i save user to a database, that works fine.

Now i dont know what the best practice is for filling content of my fragments. Fragment #2 is my main fragment, i can fill its content fine, but when i switch to the fragment #3, the list is empty - frag #3 oncreateview method is not called, but when i switch back to frag #1 and again back to the frag #3 oncreateview method is called and view is updated.

I'd really appreciate if somebody could take some time and explain what the best practice is in this case.

My questions are:

Where should i run methods for retrieving data from the database ? fragment activity or each fragment on its own?

and most important question how to update fragments in viewpager?

Also it seems that couple of my queries gets skipped and return null, although it should wait and return some values.

Code looks like this

```
responsedJson = new SynchronousHttpRequestTask().execute(httRequest).get();
```

**EDIT:**

I am using viewpager with fragment pager adapter. I configure them in OnCreate method of Fragment activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_ONE, new NewsFeed());
        _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_TWO, new MainActivity());
        _fragments.add(FRAGMENT_THREE, new FriendListActivity());


        // Setup the fragments, defining the number of fragments, the screens and titles.
        _fragmentPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return FRAGMENTS;
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
                return _fragments.get(position);
            }
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case FRAGMENT_ONE:
                        return "News feed";
                    case FRAGMENT_TWO:
                        return "Profile";
                    case FRAGMENT_THREE:
                        return "Friend list";
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }
        };
        _viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        _viewPager.setAdapter(_fragmentPagerAdapter);
        _viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        _viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

    //facebook login
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    loginfragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.hide(loginfragment);
    transaction.commit();
    //end facebook login

    }
```

SynchronousHttpRequestTask code

```
class SynchronousHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<HttpPost, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(HttpPost... request) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {

            response = httpclient.execute(request[0]);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else {
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO 
        }
        return StaticRestClient.StringToJson(responseString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code, how are you adding this fragments? If the data is concerned to a fragment in specific, you should retrieve the data from database, inside each fragment. Also I'd like to see the code for `SynchronousHttpRequestTask`

Comment: Updated my first post, thanks for checking it out.

Comment: what kind of element you want to update on your fragment? BTW are you having some error?

Comment: I want to update Expandable list, query returns Arraylist of User objects. Here is Friend list fragment code: http://pastebin.com/8R33visb

Comment: are you having some error? What is going wrong with your code?

Comment: Sorry for not answering faster. I dont have any error whatsoever. OnCreateView of FriendList is not getting called everytime i switch to it, it gets called when i go two fragments away from it, it seems it is destroyed then, i even set  offscreen page limit to 0 and that doesnt help.

Comment: I am also 99% sure there is some error with my http code. Could you please just check if everything is fine with it? here it is: http://pastebin.com/gRuQVwfu

Comment: please post the LogCat. Is some exception being thrown? It's hard to say what's going wrong without some clue.

Comment: does your `responsedJson` variable from `Get_send_data_delujoca` contains the proper value (I mean, the `success` with its value), or is it empty?

Comment: It does return value, matter of fact i was cleaning my code up, so i could send it to you and i implemented user system with sharedpreferences and suddenly it started to work. mind blown. I'm really grateful for your time and help, i'll definitely have some problems later, i'll report back then. Thank you again!